# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I get this error. I created a button to update the table. When I click the button, I get an error. How to fix it?

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function personel::update_form(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\panel\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 360 and exactly 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\panel\application\controllers\personel.php:57 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\panel\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(360): personel->update_form() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\panel\index.php(202): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\warehouse\panel\application\controllers\personel.php on line 57

**Fİle Name: personel.php** **Controller**

**MY CODES**

```
 public function update_form($id){

        $where = array( "id" => $id);

        $personel = $this->Personel_model->get($where);

        $viewData["personel"] = $personel;


        $this->load->view("personel_edit");

     }
```

**MY BUTTON CODES**

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url("personel/update_form"); ?>" class="btn-sm btn-warning">Update </a>
```

Comment: show me your view button.

Comment: you're calling `update_form` without passing an argument as expected by the method, the error should be here: `CodeIgniter.php on line 360`, make sure you're passing an `$id`

Comment: Should be like this : `href="<?php echo base_url("personel/update_form/".$id); ?>"` where $id is your record id to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You must pass an `ID` with the button to function in the controller like this.*

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url("personel/update_form/".$row->id); ?>" class="btn-sm btn-warning">Update </a>
```