# I am getting an error that I have to few arguments in my function?

Tags: php, html, class

im writing a class in php and I am getting an error stating:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function StudentAccountInquiry::get_semester(), 0 passed in /home/cg/root/632dc36089450/main.php on line 28 and exactly 1 expected in /home/cg/root/632dc36089450/main.php:14
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home/cg/root/632dc36089450/main.php(28): StudentAccountInquiry->get_semester()
>
> #1 {main}
> thrown in /home/cg/root/632dc36089450/main.php on line 14

```
<?php
class StudentAccountInquiry{
    public $semester;
    public $balance;
    
    function set_semester($semester){
        $this->semester = $semester;
    }

    function set_balance($balance){
        $this->balance = $balance;
    }

    function get_semester($semester){
        return $this->semester;
    }
    
    function get_balance($balance){
        return $this->balance;
    }

}

$fall = new StudentAccountInquiry();
$fallBalance = new StudentAccountInquiry();
$fall->set_semester('Fall 2022');
$fallBalance->set_balance('$10,000');
echo $fall->get_semester();
echo $balance->get_balance();
?>
```

It looks to me that everything is there.

Please Advise, Thanks!

Comment: Where do you think the argument is in `$fall->get_semester();`?

Comment: Oh i see, i put in a parameter that wasnt defined

Comment: No you called a method that requires a parameter but you didnt pass a param on the call OR visa versa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51666883/fatal-error-uncaught-argumentcounterror)

Answer (score 1):

get_balance and get_balance function has function arguments $semester and $balance respectively , which you actually do not need, as you just returning class variable
so you can change for function definition to this

**Old**

```
function get_semester($semester){
    return $this->semester;
}

function get_balance($balance){
    return $this->balance;
}
```

**New**

```
function get_semester(){
    return $this->semester;
}

function get_balance(){
    return $this->balance;
}
```